# How Convert.ToDateTime() parses a given string when the given culture does not know the format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

I have the following code, and it works.

```
string testDateStr = "2009.7.28 05:23:15";
DateTime testDateObj = Convert.ToDateTime(testDateStr, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

And I checked the valid formats for my culture:

```
string[] validFormats = testDateObj.GetDateTimeFormats(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

And none of them matches the "2009.7.28 05:23:15" format. I want to know how this is parsed without throwing a format exception, and what kind of hidden parsing is done when we call the Convert.ToDateTime().

Update:
I tried the following after LakshmiNarayanan's answer.

```
foreach(var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    foreach(var format in testDateObj.GetDateTimeFormats(culture))
    {
        if (format == testDateStr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(culture.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

There are cultures which actually contain the format my string is in, but still it fails to explain why it does not throw an exception when we ask it to convert using a specific culture while that culture does not know the format the string is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Convert.ToDateTime` method internally uses `DateTime.Parse` method, which is based on internal sophisticated `Lex` method. There is a bunch of rules applied to passed string. It is split into tokens and each token is analyzed. The analysis is really complex and I'm going to show only couple of rules.

If token is composed of digits and has length 3~8, then this token is going to be the year, that's why it is possible to parse `01.2014.01` string, which would produce `01 Jan 2014` result. Note that you can also parse strings like `01 2014 01` or `01\n2014\n01` giving the same result. You can separate tokens using whitespaces or `,` or `.` symbols.

If token is the name of the month, then it is going to be the month (the table or tokens is built within internal `DateTimeFormatInfo.CreateTokenHashTable` method). So it doesn't matter where do you locate `Feb` or `February`. You can equally parse `2014 1 Jan` or `2014.Jan.1`, `2014...,Jan..,..1` or even `5Jan2014` string (the last one doesn't use any separator, but it checks where the number ends, so it is successfully split into `5`, `Jan` and `2014` tokens).

If we have ambiguous string `01/04`, then the information from culture is taken to resolve the order of day/month. The order is extracted from [DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthDayPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthdaypattern.aspx). For example, for `en-US` it is `MMMM dd`, and for `en-GB` it is `dd MMMM`. There is `private static bool GetMonthDayOrder(string pattern, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, out int order)` method in internal `System.DateTimeParse` class, which is used to extract the order. If the `order` variable takes value `6`, then it is `MM/dd`, if it takes value `7`, then it is `dd/MM`. Note that it **will not** try to do some heuristics about `01/31`, only order extracted from culture is considered. Here is the code for test:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;
Assembly coreAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
Type dateTimeParseType = coreAssembly.GetType("System.DateTimeParse");
MethodInfo getMonthDayOrderMethodInfo = dateTimeParseType.GetMethod("GetMonthDayOrder", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
object[] parameters = new object[] { dtfi.MonthDayPattern, dtfi, null };
getMonthDayOrderMethodInfo.Invoke(null, parameters);
int order = (int)parameters[2];
switch (order)
{
    case -1:
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot extract information");
        break;
    case 6:
        Console.WriteLine("MM/dd");
        break;
    case 7:
        Console.WriteLine("dd/MM");
        break;
}
```

And a lot of other checks against AM/PM pattern, day of week, time suffix (for example for Korean language the `시` suffix is considered, meaning hour), etc.

The following code would produce information about culture-specific tokens:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dti = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;
dynamic hashes = dti.GetType().GetMethod("CreateTokenHashTable", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(dti, null);
var tokens = Enumerable.Repeat(new { str = "", type = "", value = "" }, 0).ToList();
foreach (dynamic hash in hashes)
    if (hash != null)
    {
        Type hashType = hash.GetType();
        tokens.Add(new { str = (string)hashType.GetField("tokenString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(hash).ToString(),
                         type = (string)hashType.GetField("tokenType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(hash).ToString(),
                         value = (string)hashType.GetField("tokenValue", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(hash).ToString() });
    }
foreach (var token in tokens.Distinct().OrderBy(t => t.type).ThenBy(t => t.value))
    Console.WriteLine("{0,10} {1} {2}", token.str, token.type, token.value);
```

For `InvariantCulture` the output is:

```
        AM 1027 0
        PM 1284 1
    Sunday DayOfWeekToken 0
       Sun DayOfWeekToken 0
    Monday DayOfWeekToken 1
       Mon DayOfWeekToken 1
   Tuesday DayOfWeekToken 2
       Tue DayOfWeekToken 2
 Wednesday DayOfWeekToken 3
       Wed DayOfWeekToken 3
       Thu DayOfWeekToken 4
  Thursday DayOfWeekToken 4
    Friday DayOfWeekToken 5
       Fri DayOfWeekToken 5
       Sat DayOfWeekToken 6
  Saturday DayOfWeekToken 6
        AD EraToken 1
      A.D. EraToken 1
         , IgnorableSymbol 0
         . IgnorableSymbol 0
   January MonthToken 1
       Jan MonthToken 1
   October MonthToken 10
       Oct MonthToken 10
  November MonthToken 11
       Nov MonthToken 11
  December MonthToken 12
       Dec MonthToken 12
  February MonthToken 2
       Feb MonthToken 2
     March MonthToken 3
       Mar MonthToken 3
       Apr MonthToken 4
     April MonthToken 4
       May MonthToken 5
      June MonthToken 6
       Jun MonthToken 6
       Jul MonthToken 7
      July MonthToken 7
       Aug MonthToken 8
    August MonthToken 8
 September MonthToken 9
       Sep MonthToken 9
         / SEP_Date 0
         - SEP_DateOrOffset 0
         日 SEP_DaySuff 0
         일 SEP_DaySuff 0
         时 SEP_HourSuff 0
         時 SEP_HourSuff 0
         T SEP_LocalTimeMark 0
         分 SEP_MinuteSuff 0
         月 SEP_MonthSuff 0
         월 SEP_MonthSuff 0
         秒 SEP_SecondSuff 0
         : SEP_Time 0
         년 SEP_YearSuff 0
         年 SEP_YearSuff 0
       GMT TimeZoneToken 0
         Z TimeZoneToken 0
```

For `fr-FR` culture (notice that `July` is included in the list as well as other tokens from `InvariantCulture`)

```
        AM 1027 0
        PM 1284 1
         h DateWordToken 0
  dimanche DayOfWeekToken 0
       Sun DayOfWeekToken 0
      dim. DayOfWeekToken 0
    Sunday DayOfWeekToken 0
     lundi DayOfWeekToken 1
    Monday DayOfWeekToken 1
      lun. DayOfWeekToken 1
       Mon DayOfWeekToken 1
   Tuesday DayOfWeekToken 2
       Tue DayOfWeekToken 2
     mardi DayOfWeekToken 2
      mar. DayOfWeekToken 2
  mercredi DayOfWeekToken 3
 Wednesday DayOfWeekToken 3
      mer. DayOfWeekToken 3
       Wed DayOfWeekToken 3
     jeudi DayOfWeekToken 4
  Thursday DayOfWeekToken 4
       Thu DayOfWeekToken 4
      jeu. DayOfWeekToken 4
      ven. DayOfWeekToken 5
  vendredi DayOfWeekToken 5
    Friday DayOfWeekToken 5
       Fri DayOfWeekToken 5
    samedi DayOfWeekToken 6
      sam. DayOfWeekToken 6
       Sat DayOfWeekToken 6
  Saturday DayOfWeekToken 6
 ap. J.-C. EraToken 1
         , IgnorableSymbol 0
         . IgnorableSymbol 0
   January MonthToken 1
     janv. MonthToken 1
   janvier MonthToken 1
       Jan MonthToken 1
      oct. MonthToken 10
       Oct MonthToken 10
   octobre MonthToken 10
   October MonthToken 10
      nov. MonthToken 11
       Nov MonthToken 11
  novembre MonthToken 11
  November MonthToken 11
      déc. MonthToken 12
  December MonthToken 12
       Dec MonthToken 12
  décembre MonthToken 12
     févr. MonthToken 2
   février MonthToken 2
  February MonthToken 2
       Feb MonthToken 2
      mars MonthToken 3
     March MonthToken 3
       Mar MonthToken 3
       Apr MonthToken 4
      avr. MonthToken 4
     avril MonthToken 4
     April MonthToken 4
       mai MonthToken 5
       May MonthToken 5
      June MonthToken 6
      juin MonthToken 6
       Jun MonthToken 6
      July MonthToken 7
     juil. MonthToken 7
   juillet MonthToken 7
       Jul MonthToken 7
       Aug MonthToken 8
      août MonthToken 8
    August MonthToken 8
     sept. MonthToken 9
       Sep MonthToken 9
 septembre MonthToken 9
 September MonthToken 9
         / SEP_Date 0
         - SEP_DateOrOffset 0
         日 SEP_DaySuff 0
         일 SEP_DaySuff 0
         时 SEP_HourSuff 0
         時 SEP_HourSuff 0
         T SEP_LocalTimeMark 0
         分 SEP_MinuteSuff 0
         月 SEP_MonthSuff 0
         월 SEP_MonthSuff 0
         秒 SEP_SecondSuff 0
         : SEP_Time 0
         년 SEP_YearSuff 0
         年 SEP_YearSuff 0
       GMT TimeZoneToken 0
         Z TimeZoneToken 0
```

Comment: That makes sense. So basically you are saying that the culture we pass in actually has no value other than make the matching logic faster?

Comment: @ΕГИІИО The culture we pass is the source of month names, month abbreviations, day names,  various suffices, etc. The format strings are not used.

Comment: Then I guess the DateSeparator/TimeSeparator are also not part of it.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО DateSeparator/TimeSeparator have meaning. You cannot parse `5:Jan:2014` string, because parser would expect time around `:` separator. But you can parse `5/Jan/2014` string, because `/` is valid DateSeparator.

Comment: You said the month names are matched using the passed in culture, but this works: `Convert.ToDateTime("2009 July 28 05:23:15", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"))` So what exactly is it doing with the given culture?

Comment: @ΕГИІИО See my updated answer. Replace `InvariantCulture` by your culture and you will see that `July` is included into hash list.

Comment: True, but I am specifically saying it to use 'fr-FR'. Are you saying it tries with all other cultures if the passed in culture has no match?

Comment: @ΕГИІИО It doesn't try other cultures. It is that `fr-FR` culture includes `July`.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО Ok, I found it. All cultures include tokens from `InvariantCulture` when the hash table is built. So in every culture you're going to have `July`, `Monday`, etc. tokens for parsing. But if you try to parse `juillet` with `InvariantCulture` or `ko-KR` culture, you will fail, so there are no tries with other cultures.

Comment: yes I too tried that :) Now everything falls into place. Thanks for spending your valuable time on this.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО If you are still interested in this question I added the information about how the order of numeric day/month is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The [Datetime.GetDateTimeFormats()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyk2998w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method does not list date in the format "2009.7.28 05:23:15" which could be because of the default cultureInfo.

However, if you check out the IFormatProvider overload for [GetDateTimeFormats(IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saw4x629%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, you could see that for culture "fr-FR", the method is able to successfully parse dates with "dot" delimiters. eg 28.07.09 5:23:15

Hence the logical assumption to how this works is that, the DateTime.Parse() runs the string through all the possible cultures, if there is not any specific culture provided, and only returns an exception when none of the cultures' string matches.

EDIT:

Digging through MSDN, the [Convert.ToDateTime(stringTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is being parsed with the DateTimeFormatInfo for the current culture.

> If value is not null, the return value is the result of invoking the
>   DateTime.Parse method on value using the formatting information in a
>   DateTimeFormatInfo object that is initialized for the current culture.
>   The value argument must contain the representation of a date and time
>   in one of the formats described in the DateTimeFormatInfo topic.

So when no specific culture is set, the [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.datetimeformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object refers to the default constructor. Referring to MSDN,

> This constructor creates a DateTimeFormatInfo object that represents
>   the date and time information of the **invariant** culture. To create a
>   DateTimeFormatInfo object for a specific culture, create a CultureInfo
>   object for that culture and retrieve the DateTimeFormatInfo object
>   returned by its CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat property.

So invariant culture is default when no culture is defined. So the Convert.ToDateTime's default string method refers to the default object of DateTimeFormatInfo, which refers to invariant culture. Which means that Convert.ToDateTime has to parse through all validations across all cultures.

Hence our assumption that validations are being checked for all culture variants is correct.

Hope It helps. Kudos, a really interesting observation.

Comment: When you don't specify the culture for GetDateTimeFormats(), it picks the default culture. Same when you use Convert.ToDateTime() without specifying culture. So I am not sure why they don't correlate. But you have a valid assumption on trying all possibile formats, and then again that's scary :)

Comment: I tried to find whether the given format is matched when parsed through all possible cultures. Surprisingly 10 cultures did contain it so that kind of explains but I ran into an another. I have updated my question now.

Comment: I've just updated the answer with an observation. I'm not really if the matchin logic is faster when no specific culture is mentioned, because I assume it has to check multiple cultures. My guess is it should be faster when a culture is defined. But I don't think this check impacts performance much though.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it mathces all cultures when no culture is specified. But even when the culture is specified, we can still convert without errors. Any idea why it works?

Answer (score 0):

Possible ways

```
  dateString = "05/01/1996";
  ConvertToDateTime(dateString);
  dateString = "Tue Apr 28, 2009";
  ConvertToDateTime(dateString);
  dateString = "Wed Apr 28, 2009";
  ConvertToDateTime(dateString);
  dateString = "06 July 2008 7:32:47 AM";
  ConvertToDateTime(dateString);
  dateString = "17:32:47.003";
  ConvertToDateTime(dateString);
  // Convert a string returned by DateTime.ToString("R").
  dateString = "Sat, 10 May 2008 14:32:17 GMT";
  ConvertToDateTime(dateString);
  // Convert a string returned by DateTime.ToString("o").
  dateString = "2009-05-01T07:54:59.9843750-04:00";
  ConvertToDateTime(dateString);


int year=2009;
int month=7;
int day=28;
int hr=5;
int min=23;
int s=15;   

DateTime testDateObj = Convert.ToDateTime(year, month, day, hr, min, s);
```

or simply

```
DateTime testDateObj = Convert.ToDateTime(2009, 7, 28, 5, 23, 15);
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question correctly. I wanted an explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Try using class DateTimeFormatInfo for have information abount datetime format i your culture.

Comment: I wanted to know how it works when you DO NOT specify the culture.

Comment: It takes standard culture settings

Comment: But my standard culture (local) does not have THAT specific format listed. Hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:-Try this:

```
string testDateStr = "2009.7.28 05:23:15";
    string testDateObj = Convert.ToDateTime(testDateStr).Date.ToString("d");

    string[] validFormats = (Convert.ToDateTime(testDateObj)).GetDateTimeFormats();
    foreach(string s in validFormats)
    {
       lblresult.Text += s;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try this? I see obvious compilation errors.

Comment: sorry i write the previous post in hurry, please try with updated code.

Comment: Still it fails to explain how the convertion at line 2 is done.