# Particular DateTime exception

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to convert to DateTime some strings with this format **"MMM-yy"**. I'm working with the culture **"{es-ES}"**.

It works fine with all month except with *March* (In spanish *Marzo*).
This throws me this exception:

> 'Convert.ToDateTime("Mar-13")' threw an exception of type
>   'System.FormatException' System.DateTime {System.FormatException}

I've tried:

```
string format = "yyyyMM";
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
result = DateTime.ParseExact("Mar-13", format, provider);
```

and this:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("Mar-13");
```

This works fine for example with:

"Jun-13"

"Feb-13"

"Nov-13"

...

**EDIT**
The real problem is with:

DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("Ene-13"); -> ok

DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("Feb-13"); -> ok

DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("Mar-13"); -> crash

DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("Abr-13"); -> ok

....

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have strings in spanish culture or not? `Dic-13` cannot be converted to a data using the InvariantCulture even if you fix the format string to `MMM-yy`

Comment: Yes I have in spanish, I try with InvariantCulture because I found it like a posible solution

Comment: Try with `CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("ES-es")` and fix the format to MMM-yy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date string `"Mar-13"` doesn't match your format `"yyyyMM"`. Your format should be `MMM-yy`.

You should see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In your format

> "MMM" - The abbreviated name of the month.
>
> "yy" - The year, from 00 to 99.

EDIT:

For your question why `Convert.ToDateTime("Mar-13");` is failing. You need to look at the following lines of code:

```
var currentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
var monthNames = currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames;
var dayOfWeeks = currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames;
```

If you watch the returned values in debugger, You will see that for the culture `es-ES` there is a **match between Month Name and Day name** and that is on `mar`.

- Marzo/March as Month
- Martes/Tuesday as day

Both of these uses the same abbreviation i.e. `Mar`. Since `Convert.ToDateTime` would try to use possible formats for the string it fails to recognize `Mar` as Month or Day Name. That is why you get exception.

It is always a good idea to use `DateTime.ParseExact` and specify a single or [multiple possible formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: but for example if I do "Abr-13" it works fine.
Only crash with "Mar"

Comment: @MCSI, `DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("Mar-13", "MMM-yy", new CultureInfo("es-ES"));` this should work fine.

Comment: @MCSI, with your format, there is no way your string would get parsed. This `DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("Abr-13", "yyyyMM", new CultureInfo("es-ES"));`  will throw an exception.

Comment: OK, you'r right. the real problem is when you don't pass the format, for example:

Convert.ToDateTime("Mar-13"); works perfect with the other months

Comment: @MCSI, Updated my answer with detailed explanation for the behaviour. It is mainly because of matching Month Name and Day Name.

Answer (score 4):

Your format and value don't match.  Try this instead:

```
string format = "MMM-yy";
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
result = DateTime.ParseExact("Mar-13", format, provider);
```

**EDIT**

For the `es-ES` format provider, my guess is that `Mar` is ambiguous between *Marzo* (March) and *Martes* (Tuesday).  You should be fine if you use `ParseExact` with the *proper* format:

```
string format = "MMM-yy";
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");

// fails
result = DateTime.Parse("Mar-13", provider);

// works
result = DateTime.ParseExact("Mar-13", format, provider);
result = DateTime.ParseExact("Abr-13", format, provider);
```

**EDIT 2**

This appears to be a [known bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/822536/datetime-parse-result-in-exception-when-the-format-is-rfc1123-pattern-and-locale-is-a-latin-one#).  Their workaround is to use a *similar* culture, however if your date format is known, I'd recommend using `ParseExact` to *explicitly* define the format rather than letting the framework try and *infer* the format.

Comment: If you use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` on a non Spanish system, then trying to convert "abr-13" will fail.

Comment: you are right too, but as I said in the previous answer... the real problem is when you don't pass the format, for example: Convert.ToDateTime("Mar-13"); works perfect with the other months

Answer (score 2):

Reference to my answer about logic behind automatic DateTime parsing: [How Convert.ToDateTime() parses a given string when the given culture does not know the format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809884/how-convert-todatetime-parses-a-given-string-when-the-given-culture-does-not-k/22856050#22856050)

You can automatically parse `Abr-13` in `es-ES` culture, because `Abr` can be matched only as `MonthToken`. But in case of `Mar-13` - `Mar` can be matched as `MonthToken` and also it can be matched as `DayOfWeekToken` (Tuesday), so `DateTime.Parse`/`Convert.ToDateTime` methods are confused and throw exception.

If you execute the code from referenced answer against `es-ES` culture, you would see the following in the output:

```
   mar DayOfWeekToken 2
   Mar MonthToken 3
```

There are no multiple matches for full months names though, so you can safely parse 'marzo', 'abril' values.

Since `DateTime.Parse`/`Convert.ToDateTime` methods are confused by this duality of `Mar` value, we need to provide a hint to it using `DateTime.ParseExact` method:

```
DateTime output = DateTime.ParseExact("Mar-13", "MMM-yy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the correct CultureInfo and fix the format string

```
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("ES-es");
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("Abr-13", "MMM-yy", provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Spanish culture info in association with the "MMM-yy" format :

```
        string format = "MMM-yy";
        DateTime result;
        CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
        result = DateTime.ParseExact("mar-13", format, provider);
        result = DateTime.ParseExact("abr-13", format, provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

On my system the current culture is **en-US** the following code will fail when trying to convert abril (April):

```
string format = "MMM-yy";
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
result = DateTime.ParseExact("abr-13", format, provider);
```

Therefore on my system I have to create a Spanish culture for the code to work:

```
string format = "MMM-yy";
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
result = DateTime.ParseExact("abr-13", format, provider);
```

So you need to be aware what culture your code is running on and take the proper action.